# Insert Data into Single MySQL Table Concurrently by Multi-thread in C++

Tags: c++, mysql, database, multithreading

I am doing an experiment that concurrently insert data into a MySQL table by multi-thread.

Here is partial code in C++.

```
    bool query_thread(const char* cmd, MYSQL* con) {
      if( !query( cmd, con ) ) {
        return 0;
      }
      return 1;
    }
    int main() {
          ........
      if(mysql_query(m_con, "CREATE TABLE tb1 (model INT(32), handle INT(32))") != 0) {
        return 0;
      }
        
      thread thread1(query_thread, "INSERT INTO tb1 VALUES (1,1)", m_con);
      thread thread2(query_thread, "INSERT INTO tb1 VALUES (2,2)", m_con);
      thread thread3(query_thread, "INSERT INTO tb1 VALUES (3,3)", m_con);
      thread1.join();
      thread2.join();
      thread3.join();
    }
```

But the MySQL error message is issued.

> error cmd: INSERT INTO tb1 VALUES (1,1)
>
> Lost connection to MySQL server during query
>
> Segmentation fault

My questions are as following.

1. Is it because the MySQL cannot accept concurrently insertion? Or bad use of multi-thread.
2. By multi-thread insertion as above, does it help to speed up the program? I understand the best way are multiple insert per query and LOAD DATA INFILE. But I just want to know if this way can help.

Comment: mysql connection handles are not thread safe. Each one of your threads should have its own connection handle.

Comment: I see. But if each thread has its own connection, does it help to speed up the program or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each thread must have:

- own database connection
- own transaction
- own cursor

This, however will not make your inserts much faster. In short, the innodb log (journal) is essentially serial which limits server total insert rate. Read mysql performance blog (percona / mariadb) for details. Certainly there are parameters to tweak and there seem to have been advances with recently.

Comment: Thanks! But why it can't be faster? Is it because they are queued and performed in sequence?

Comment: For example, 10 threads and each insert 10 rows V.S. 1 thread insert 100 rows. Is it no different?

Comment: Consider 2 bottlenecks -- CPU and disk. For the earlier, concurrent queries help, but it only matters if your queries are complex. For the latter, it's the throughput (large transactions) or commits (small transactions), which only matters when the dataset is large (vs. RAM / commit log). By all means try it out!

Comment: Multithreading can have extreme performance improvements with mysql.  
I've years of struggles with mysql and multithreading can speed up inserts at least by 10 times, writes up to 1000 times.  
It highly depends on the sort of query and your disk capabilities, use monitoring tools to find out how saturated your IO/memory is.

Comment: @John The OP question is about bulk insert. Throughput is limited by the db engine. MySQL/Innodb serves connections in own threads, but all inserts have to go through "redo log" (a.k.a. journal, please where new data is written before it reaches table on disk). The "log" quickly fills up and must be flushed. Last time I checked (2 years ago), log flush was single-threaded. While some settings can be tweaked, overall there's a throughput limit imposed by redo log. It's in the name of consistency should the machine crash.

Comment: @DimaTisnek Bulk inserts will greatly benefit from multithreading.  There are many different scenarios but consider that almost every INSERT includes READs.  
Indexes need to be checked, triggers processed, foreign keys, etc.  
I've just had a real life example here, I inserted 430 million rows from one table to another.  
With one thread the speed was about 3k rows per second.
With 32 threads I reached 35k rows per second and IO/CPU was still 50% idle.